# Why my div doesn't take all remaining space?

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

My website is having really odd behaviours which i don't understand.

Why my top navigation menu and contact button isn't showing up?

I think the 100% height of `class='intro'` is messing up. It's taking too much height (950px, should be less). I've set it to 100% height because i wanted it to take all remaining space of the first section, but it takes up more height than that.

I'm so lost, i don't even know what to ask exactly.. What's going wrong here?

https://cgonen.github.io/testpage/ <-- this page.

Comment: Hi, you need to post the relevant code to reproduce your problem as a [mcve] in your post on SO.

Comment: so should i delete my question? And rebuild the website minimal.

Comment: You should just replicate the problem with only the relevant code so we don't have to go to a 3rd party site (which changes over time, making this post irrelevant over time to other people with the same problem) and sift through a bunch of irrelevant code.

Comment: Hey Michael, I think the problem with that at times is, demos on Stack are not always functional, so then people create a non working demo here and link another demo externally. Not saying that is the case here, but it has been for me on more than one account.

Answer (score 0):

Add position:absolute to your topmenu like so,

update:

```
.hero {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1040px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("img/goodtech-o.jpg");
    border-bottom: 2px solid seagreen;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me to have to use position absolute.. plus it removes responsiveness. Also, the .intro div has button and a paragraph inside of it which disappeared too. Why doesn't it work like.. normal..?  since the .hero is a normal display flex. The menu is a normal display bock.

Comment: My mistake I didnt see that. Place position:absolute for your hero. As for responsiveness...regardless, your image was not responsive, all others are.

Comment: See update code. Notice, width and max-width along with position.